People using comments to answer questions
I have been noticing new questions often have answers in the comments instead of the answer list.
What is the rationale behind this?
I have seen this with users that have a lot of reputation too, so it does not seem to be user error.

Please before considering posting: Google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including using 'site:'. For meta questions search site /help pages & Q&A at meta sites & [meta.se]. How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

I think context matters.
I sometimes post very partial answers, which I don't believe are good enough by my standards to be a full answer. Sometimes these turn into much longer answers, and end up being a signpost for myself to dig further.
They might not be sure it's the answer—until later in the comments thread. Sometimes it's because the possible answer is too simple. Other times, it's too strange, and you don't know how it works either.
Occasionally, some users just want to avoid potential downvotes, don't want to spend the time writing a full answer, or want to leave a signpost for someone else to post a full answer.
'It Depends' isn't a satisfying answer—but 'it depends'. This could have been a comment, but it doesn't quite fit as one.

Often an educated guess gives the right solution. But there's still a long way from "try this" to a proper answer (which for me means complete examples, pictures if relevant, references explanations,, etc.)  I can point someone in the right direction (and they can write an answer), but that doesn't necessarily mean I  have the time (or desire) to do a proper write-up on it.
